# Dequeue is not working when consumer is dead

Tags: oracle, queue

I have a queue propagation form source_queue to dest_queue@dblink the payload is an anydata. A subscriber is added to source_queue:

```
sys.aq$_agent('CONSUMER', dest_queue@dblink, null);
```

Now I wanted to know if there is a way to use dbms_aq.dequeue at source_queue if the enqueued message could not be propagated, because the network to dest_queue@dblink goes down for a while. I tried it with the following:

```
m_queueOpts.consumer_name := 'CONSUMER';
m_queueOpts.dequeue_mode := dbms_aq.remove;

DBMS_aq.dequeue (
queue_name => 'source_queue',
dequeue_options => m_queueOpts,
message_properties => m_msgProps,
payload => m_data,
msgid => m_msgId
);
```

but I got an error:ORA-25247: CONSUMER is not a recipient of specified message

which is right, because the reciepient is on dest_queue@dblink.

but I want to dequeue or remove the message from source_queue if they could not propagated. Is there a other way of dequeueing from source_queue?

I tried it, to set a message_id at queueOptions as well, but still I was not able to dequeue the message.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found answer on some Oracle FAQ: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/qfaqs.htm

They advice to remove subscriber in order to remove all messages for that target (consumer, address). Interesting that for AQ you may not have subscribers, but for removing staled messages you can add one, then remove it, like that:

```
declare
    p$src_queue    varchar2(30) := 'source_queue';
    p$consumer    varchar2(30) := 'CONSUMER';
    p$dst_queue    varchar2(100) := 'dest_queue@dblink';
--
    subscriber SYS.AQ$_AGENT;
begin
    subscriber := SYS.AQ$_AGENT(p$consumer, p$dst_queue, NULL);

    DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER(
        queue_name => p$src_queue,
        subscriber => subscriber
    );

    subscriber := SYS.AQ$_AGENT(p$consumer, p$dst_queue, NULL);

    DBMS_AQADM.REMOVE_SUBSCRIBER(
        queue_name => p$src_queue,
        subscriber => subscriber
    );
end;
/
```